# receiveMessage not retrieving requested messageAttributes

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to receive messages from a SQS which contain two messageAttributes (`commId` and `retailerId`). I receive the messages like this:

```
public List<Message> receiveMessages(final String queueUrl, final String... messageAttributeNames) {
    final var receiveMessageRequest = ReceiveMessageRequest.builder()
        .queueUrl(queueUrl)
        .maxNumberOfMessages(10)
        .messageAttributeNames(messageAttributeNames)
        .build();
    return sqsClient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).messages();
}
```

and call my function with the following params:

```
final var messages = sqsQueue.receiveMessages(queueUrl, "All");
```

I also tried to use the explicit messageAttributeNames, looking like this:

```
final var messages = sqsQueue.receiveMessages(queueUrl, "commId", "retailerId");
```

In my tests I'm sending the messageAttributes to a SQS in a [localstack docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/localstack/localstack), and retrieving them works perfectly fine. However, as soon as I try to receive the messages from the actual AWS SQS, the messageAttributes are always emtpy.

I have checked that the messageAttributes are present, when receiving a message through the AWS Console they are included:

```
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "92206ce4-0be7-58bd-9a70-35a791da05c4",
  "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:...:n...",
  "Message": "...",
  "Timestamp": "2021-06-16T06:19:41.190Z",
  "SignatureVersion": "1",
  "Signature": "...",
  "SigningCertURL": "...",
  "UnsubscribeURL": "....",
  "MessageAttributes": {
    "commId": {
      "Type": "Number",
      "Value": "12345"
    },
    "retailerId": {
      "Type": "Number",
      "Value": "67890"
    }
  }
}
```

All I found when searching for a solution was always to set the messageAttributeNames, but that's what I'm doing, and in theory it should work - as my tests are proving. Does anyone has any hints at what I could be missing / am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the messageAttributes actually weren't at the Message, but within it - I needed to chang ethe deserialization of the message content...